# Changing and Recompiling Android source code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, dex

After decompiling an Android application, I am able to view its source code/Java classes by opening the classes.dex file using jd-gui. I need to add a few lines of code to the application before recompiling it and installing the modified app onto a phone. The problem is that even though I can view the source code, I am unable to add code to it. Is there anyway I can add code to the application instead of only being able to view it? I have tried importing into Eclipse, but I cannot obviously import the classes.dex file, and need a way to do that.

Comment: You can't change the APK directly like this. You need to go all the way through the pipeline: Java source -> Java bytecode -> Dex bytecode -> package the APK -> sign the APK. By the way, what are you trying to achieve? To hack a someone else's app?

Comment: maybe ask for someone's code and then add your few lines if you get the source

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [APKTool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2213985). Also check out this [Smali coding](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2193735) guide. Not easy as you think.